# Problem installing Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded [Eclipse Neon](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) for Ubuntu 16.04, but when I run the `eclipse` executable, I have some error (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/25918638/).
How shall I solve the problem?

I have installed Oracle's JVM, JRE, and maybe also JDK (I don't know how to verify that) since a  few months ago. Does Eclipse have problem working with the preinstalled JVM, JRE and maybe also JDK?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: `java.version=9-ea` and `java.vendor=Oracle Corporation`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Java 9. Eclipse Neon does not run with Java 9 unless you modify the eclipse.ini, and even when you do that it does not support Java 9 language features.

The current release of Eclipse is Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a). This is the first release of Eclipse to fully support Java 9.